# Why does the same Http Client code work in Java 8 but fail in Java 6?

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient 4 to post some data to an endpoint URL like so..

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.example.com");
String payload = "some crap";

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

If I try this code with Java 6, I get a Connection reset exception during the SSL handshake, here is a snippet of what I see when SSL debugging is on..

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 177
[Raw write]: length = 182
binary crap here like '00A0: 00 11 00 02 00 12 00 04'
handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

But if I use Java 8, the same code works fine.

So it looks like there was something in the Java 6 request that the server I am calling didn't like that made it break the connection during handshake. But I am not certain what that is.

Is it the certs maybe? Because in the SSL debugging of the Java 8 client, I also see...

```
  ***
 Found trusted certificate:
 [
 Version: V3
 Subject: CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
```

whereas I didn't see this in Java 6.

Comment: The Java 6 JRE is **old**. It probably doesn't support any of the TLS protocols your endpoint supports. Run your endpoint through [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) or, if you want more privacy, use [sslyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze). Determine what TLS protocols the endpoint supports and compare them to those [Java 6 supports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html).

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider for letting me know about SSL labs, I can see in the handshake simulation section that the server closes the connection for Java6 client, but I still don't know why. I know the server supports TLSv1 which Java 6 has, so it the cipher suites? or the Elliptic curves? or the Server Name Indication (SNI)? All of these are differences between Java 6 and 7 (which worked).